# Upload Excel Spreadsheet into Access that has VBA code in columns

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I currently have a Access Database that an employee manually enters records monthly. Instead I want to upload an excel spreadsheet and populate all columns in the database. The problem is that some of the columns have VBA code that does some calculation, when I upload the spreadsheet, the calculations do not happen, only when you type a value it calculates.

Is there a way around this?

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Database

Dim strStopReading As String
Dim datDate As Date

Private Sub AdjWater_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    Call UpdateCharges
End Sub

Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()
    varLastReading = StopReading
End Sub

Private Sub Form_BeforeInsert(Cancel As Integer)
    Me.StartReading = varLastReading

    If Me.Parent.BillingMethod = 3 Then
        If IsNull(Me.Date) Then
            AmountCharged = curWater
        Else
            AmountCharged = GetRate(Me.Date, Me.Parent.strWaterCode)
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Gallons_Change()
    Call UpdateCharges
End Sub

Private Sub StartReading_Change()

    If Not IsNumeric(StartReading.Text) Then Exit Sub

    If Not IsNull(StopReading) Then
        Gallons = StopReading - StartReading.Text
        UpdateCharges
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub StopReading_Change()
    If Not IsNumeric(StopReading.Text) Then Exit Sub

    If Not IsNull(StartReading) Then
        Gallons = StopReading.Text - StartReading
        UpdateCharges
    End If

End Sub

Public Sub UpdateCharges()
    Dim blnChkNum As String
    Dim curWaterRate As Currency
    Dim curSewerRate As Currency
    Dim curMinRate As Currency

    'if date is null then use current rate
    If IsNull(Me.Date) Then
        curWaterRate = curWater
        curSewerRate = curSewer
        curMinRate = curMinChg
    Else
        curWaterRate = GetRate(Me.Date, Me.Parent.strWaterCode)
        curSewerRate = GetRate(Me.Date, Me.Parent.strSewerCode)
        curMinRate = GetRate(Me.Date, Me.Parent.strMinChgCode)
    End If

    If Me.ActiveControl.Properties("Name") = "txtGallonsToInvoice" Then 
'txtGallonsToInvoice is active
    blnChkNum = IsNumeric(txtGallonsToInvoice.Text) 'check the text - it may 
differ from saved value
        If blnChkNum Then
            'update amount charged for water
            If Me.Parent.BillingMethod = 2 Then AmountCharged = 
txtGallonsToInvoice.Text / 1000 * curWaterRate
            If Me.Parent.BillingMethod = 3 Then AmountCharged = curWaterRate
            'update sewer
            If blnSewer = True Then
                SewerChg = txtGallonsToInvoice.Text / 1000 * curSewerRate
            Else
                SewerChg = 0
            End If
        End If
    Else 'Another control has the focus
        blnChkNum = IsNumeric(txtGallonsToInvoice) 'check the value - you 
can't access the text without the focus
        If blnChkNum Then
            'update amount charged for water
            If Me.Parent.BillingMethod = 2 Then AmountCharged = 
txtGallonsToInvoice / 1000 * curWaterRate
            If Me.Parent.BillingMethod = 3 Then AmountCharged = curWaterRate
            'update sewer
            If blnSewer = True Then
                SewerChg = txtGallonsToInvoice / 1000 * curSewerRate
            Else
                SewerChg = 0
            End If
        End If
    End If

If strRateGroup <> "TB" Then 'skip min charge for Houston Ship Repair
    If AmountCharged < curMinRate Then
       AmountCharged = curMinRate
       Me.Min_Water_Chg = True
    Else
        Me.Min_Water_Chg = False
    End If
Else
   Me.Min_Water_Chg = False
End If

End Sub

Private Sub txtGallonsToInvoice_Change()
    UpdateCharges
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you mean "some of the columns have VBA code"... or do you mean "some of the Excell cells have formulas"?

Comment: Some of the columns in  Access

Comment: Show the VBA code. Is there a FORM involved in Access or is someone typing directly into a table?

Comment: check out my code now.

Basically, I have an excel spreadsheet that keeps track of water meters.

It has a 'StartReading' and a 'StopReading'

I want it to calculate the cost when I import the spreadsheet. It does not do this.

It only calculates the cost if I type it in.

Comment: I'm *guessing* you have an Excel file where people enter data and that file has formula's that will calculate cost *IF* someone types it in? Somehow you import the Excel file into Access (manually? using code?) and you want to calculate a cost in Access automatically? My suggestion is to automate the import of Excel, then run a query to update all the costs. The code you posted is from your Access form. Who will fill out the Excel file since you don't want to use Access? Please be specific when mentioning "it" as I don't want to assume which application you mean.

Comment: I have an excel file that has StartReading and StopReading, the excel file does not calculate.

I would like to upload the excel file to the access database where the access database will calculate the imported excel file.

The access database calculates if I type in a StartReading and StopReading.

But, if I import the excel file to populate the StartReading and Stopreading, the access database does nothing.

Comment: I saw some of the code you have in your form.  I assume that form is using some table containing either all or part of your 'Readings" (let's call that table 'Readings'). If your Excel file is imported and appended to 'Readings', why not just add a button to that form that says 'Calculate All' or 'Calculate Latest' or 'Calculate Missing'? That could use a query that performs the calculation and updates the table... or you could run the query manually.  Is your import automated, or manual?